# Prove that the space of left translation of $C(G)$ is a $T_0$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, topological-groups

Given a topological group ($G, *, \tau$), a bounded continuous real value function $f$ on $G$ and a fixed $x \in G$, define $L_x(f)$ to be another function such that $L_x(f)(g) = f(x^{-1}g) \forall g \in G$ and call $L_x(f)$ *the left translate of $f$ by $x$*. It is not hard to see that for any $g \in G$, $L_g$ will map elements from $C_B(G)$ back to itself and the set of all $L_g$ will be a group under composition.

We denote the set of all bounded continuous real value function on $G$ by $C_B(G)$ and one can check that $d^*(f, g) = sup_{x \in G}|f(x) - g(x)|$ will be a metric on $C_B(G)$. Let $\tau_{d^*}$ be the metric topology generated by $d^*$, $\alpha(G)$ = {$L_x|x \in G$}, $e_f(O)$ = {$L_g \in \alpha(G)|L_g(f) \in O$} where $O$ is a open set in ($C_B(G), d*$) and $\mathscr{A}$ = {$e_f(O)|f \in C_B(G), O$ is open in $(C_B(G), d^*)$}.

One can check that $\mathscr{A}$ is a subbase of a topology. We call $\tau_{\mathscr{A}}$ the pointwise convergence topology. For any $f \in C_B(G)$, define $A_f =$ {$L_x(f) | x \in G$}.

**(Latest Edit Part 1)**:

//

Define $X_f$ to be the closure of $A_f$ with respect to $\tau_{d^*}$ and call it the *left orbit* of $f$. We call $f$ *left almost periodic* iff $X_f$ compact with respect to $\tau_{d^*}$. Now let $A$ be the set of all continuous and left almost periodic functions defined on $G$. Then for each $x \in G$, $L_x (A) \subseteq A$. Further we assign the space $A^A$ the pointwise topology (the same way how we define $\tau_{\mathscr{A}})$. Let $\overline{\alpha(G)}$ be the closure of $\alpha(G)$ with respect to the pointwise topology.

We can see for any $f \in A$, $L_x(f) \in X_f$. In the rest of the post, we only focus on $L_x|_{A}$. In the rest of the post, please assume all $L_x$ is only defined on $A$ instead of the whole $C_B(G)$.

//

**(End of Latest Edit Part 1)**

**(Latest Edit Part 2)**

//

Used fact:

a. If ($X, d$) is compact metric space and $K$ the group of isometries defined on $X$ (under composition). Here we use $d^*$ as well but $d^*(f, h)$ = $sup_{g \in G} d(f(g), h(g))$. Then ($K, \tau_{d^*}$) is a topological group and $\tau_{d^*}$ is the same as the topology generated by pointwise convergence. Further ($K, \tau_{d^*}$) is compact.

b. If we equip the space $\times_{f \in A} X_f$ with the pointwise convergence topology, then $\overline{\alpha(G)}$ will be a compact subset.

c. We observe $L_x$ is always a isometry from $\tau_{d^*}$ to $\tau_{d^*}$ and hence every element in ($\overline{\alpha(G)}$, $\tau_{\mathscr{A}}$) will be isometry. Let $K_f$ be the set of all isometries that maps from $X_f$ to $X_f$. 
Inside the book, it says the following (please check (c)):

[image]

Here I guess it wants me to prove $\alpha(G)$ is isomorphic $K_f$ so that the "natural" mapping is $L_x \rightarrow (L_x)_{f \in A}$ and I did that. Please feel free to provide your comments to this one. Hence $\alpha(G)$ is a topological group.

//

**(End of Latest Edit Part 2)**

For any topological group, being $T_0$ can imply being Hausdorff (check "General Topology" by John Kelly Chapter 3 Exercise S Questions f) so as a corollary if ($G, *, \tau$) is compact, then then mapping $g \rightarrow L_g$ will be a homeomorphism.

Edit: When I have real value function $f$ on $G$, $L_{h_1}(f)$ and $L_{h_2}(f)$, I want another real value function $g$ such that $g$ is uniformly close to $L_{h_1}(f)$ but not $L_{h_2}(f)$. In a compact topological group, I do not know if there are any other tools I can use to "separate" they two by some preimage of continuous function. If I can, then probably I can adjust that function so that it will be uniformly close to $L_{h_1}(f)$.

Edit again: Thanks for Alex's comment, I will add some important details that I missed in the question.

**(Latest Edit Part 3)**

//

Now I will address Alex's questions

1. $\mathscr{A}$ is a family of subsets of $\alpha(G)$ but each element of $\mathscr{A}$ does not contain mapping from $C_B(G)$ but mapping that maps $C_B(G)$ to $C_B(G)$. For example, you will see in the latest edit that $L_x(f) \in X_f \forall f \in X_f$. My previous post might confuse you because I missed some important details but this time it should be more clear.
2. In the new definition, I only focus on those $f$ such that ($X_f, d^*$) is compact. Originally, $L_x$ is defined on the whole $C_B(G)$ space and now I only want $L_x|_{A}$. Now given $X_f$ compact, I am trying to show that the mapping $g \rightarrow L_g$ is continuous ... Will post the proof once I am done.

Comment: It seems that topological groups in your sense do not have to satisfy any separation axioms. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right .... I used to see lots of people use the term "separation axiom" when talking about $T_0, T_1$ and these properties and I saw these properties on the wiki page of "separation axiom" as well. So I naively add it into the title .....

Comment: It is not clear, in which space is taken the closure $\overline{\alpha(G)}$ of $\alpha(G)$. Also, if you wish to show that the space $(\alpha(G),\tau_\mathcal A)$ is Hausdorff you need to show that it is a topological group. To show that the mapping $g\to L_g$ is a homeomorphism you also need to show that it is continuous.

Comment: To find an other real value function $g$ such that $g$ is uniformly close to $L_{h_1}(f) \in C_B(G)$ but not $L_{h_2}(f) \in C_B(G)$, it suffices to pick $g=L_{h_1}+\varepsilon h$, for any function $h\in C_B(G)$ and sufficiently small $\varepsilon$.

Comment: We have that $\mathcal A$ is a family of subsets of $\alpha(G)$, which consists of *maps* (I guess, bijective) of $C_B(G)$. Therefore $\mathcal A$ can be naturally considered as a subbase of a topology on $\alpha(G)$, not on the cartesian product $X=\prod\{ X_f:f\in C_B(G)\}$ of *orbits* $X_f$ (and I don’t see how $X$ is considered as a fucntion space). We can embed $\alpha(G)$ to $X$ mapping each $L_x\in\alpha(G)$ to a point $\{L_x(f):f\in C_B(G)\}$. But, anyway, if this embedding is not surjective, then $\mathcal A$ is not a subbase of a topology of $X$, since it does not cover $X$.

Comment: The net $\{L_{g_\lambda}\}$ not necessarily converges to $L_g$ pointwise. For instance, if $G$ is $\Bbb R$ edowed with the usual topology, $f(x)=\sin x^2$ for all $x\in G$, $g_n=\tfrac 1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $g=0$. Because of this $f$,  $\mathcal A$ generates the discrete topology on $\alpha(G)$. On the other hand, the convergence holds provided $f$ is uniformly continuous (in particular, when $G$ is compact).

Comment: Anyway, we already proved that $\alpha(G)$ endowed with a topology generated by the subbase $\mathcal A$ is Hausdorff. But the question, whether it is a topological group remains open.

Comment: At last, I recall that if $G$  is not $T_0$ then the map $g\mapsto L_g$ can be non-injective (for instance, when $|G|>1$ and it is endowed with the antidiscrete topology).

Comment: Hi, Alex. I am very sorry for the delayed responses. Recently I lost my copy of J. Kelly's textbook and could not check the original question. I got it back and let me address your questions. I edited the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y\in G$ such that $L_x$ and $L_y$ are distinct elements of $\alpha(G)$. Therefore there exists a function $f\in C_B(G)$ such that $L_x(f)\ne L_y(f)$, that is $L_x(f)(g)\ne L_y(f)(g)$ for some $g\in G$. Pick $0<\varepsilon<|L_x(f)(g)-L_y(f)(g)|/2$ and put $O_x=\{h\in C_B(G): d^*(h,L_x(f))<\varepsilon\}$ and $O_y=\{h\in C_B(G): d^*(h,L_y(f))<\varepsilon\}$. Then $e_f(O_x)$ and $e_f(O_y)$ are disjoint, $L_x\in e_f(O_x)$, $L_y\in e_f(O_y)$, that is $\alpha(G)$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: You are right. As you mentioned, it is not that difficult .... But thank you for your help and I will add those details you mentioned in your comment.